# Issue with JavaScript splice() method

Tags: javascript, splice

I'm getting mixed results by using the splice method in JS with the following example:

```
var test = function(x){  
    var f = x.toString().length;
    var bb = [];
    for (i=0;i<f;i++){bb.push('a');}
    console.log(bb);
    for (i=bb.length; i>-1; i=i-3){bb.splice(Number((i-2)),1,'b');}
    console.log(bb);    
};              
test (412289847863);
```

When the length of the input number is 4, 7, 10, 13 and so on, the last element of 'bb' turn to 'b' and I can't see why. As I see it, it should always be 'a'. Why isn't it?

Comment: What is this function supposed to do? Seems like you are doing a lot of unnecessary stuff there.

Comment: I'm pretty new to this so I guess you're right.The 'bb' array would serve as a kind of prototype. I can then replace the 'a' and 'b' with specific values from two other arrays. For example, a 'b' can have a value from any of the two arrays, while the a can have a value from only one of them. Idk if this makes sense.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you want to to with this function? Have an array of a certain length and replace every `n`th key with a different value?

Comment: Yes. As you count from right to left, starting from the second character (count begins at 1, the last character), increasing by 3. So 2,5,8,11 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comments you can try this code. You only need one loop and should avoid splice since it's very costly and not needed if you want to replace just one single element at a time.

```
function test(a){
    var l = a.toString().length;
    var bb = [];
    for (var i = l;i>0;i-=1){
        bb[i-1] = ((l-i+2)%3!=0)?"a":"b";
    }
    console.log(bb);
}

test(1343332);
```